# eclipseLink 2.5/2.6 on android studio 2.0

Tags: java, android, jpa, eclipselink

I tried to use EclipseLink on android, but got the following error with eclipseLink 2.5.

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\njava.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)\nCaused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)\n\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)\n\t... 12 more\n","tool":"Dex"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.`enter code here`

The error message did not tell me what classes caused the error.

If using eclipseLink 2.6, got the following error. It seems the weaving behavior is changed from 2.5.1.

Employee is not abstract and does not override abstract method _persistence_setLinks(ItemLinks) in PersistenceWeavedRest

```
@Entity(name = "Employee")
@Table(name = "Employee")    
public class Employee {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private Date hiredDate;

        //getter/setter methods
    }
```

Thanks for any help.